# How to reference predefined variables when creating Rule target input transformation in EventBridge in AWS CDK

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-event-bridge

When adding SQS target to the rule, I want to transform input to contain both original message and a rule name like this:

```json
{
 "originalEvent": {...},
 "ruleName": "myRule"
}
```

According to [AWS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-transform-target-input.html#eb-transform-input-predefined), this should be possible by using predefined variables (`<aws.events.event.json>` and `<aws.events.rule-name>`). However, I wasn't able to find a way to achieve this using AWS CDK.

It this not supported by CDK now?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any way to retrieve the full event JSON in the CDK docs, but you can use [`EventField.fromPath`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-events.EventField.html#static-fromwbrpathpath) method to retrieve specific fields of the original event. By using that you can reconstruct the original event if you know which are the event fields.

So if your original event is `{ foo: "foo", bar: "bar" }` you can do something like:

```js
import * as events from '@aws-cdk/aws-events';
import * as sqs from '@aws-cdk/aws-sqs';
import { SqsQueue } from '@aws-cdk/aws-events-targets';

declare const fooEventRule: events.Rule
declare const ruleTargetInput: events.RuleTargetInput
declare const queue: sqs.Queue

fooEventRule.addTarget(new SqsQueue(queue, {
    message: events.RuleTargetInput.fromObject({
        originalEvent: {
            foo: events.EventField.fromPath('$.foo'),
            bar: events.EventField.fromPath('$.bar')
        },
        ruleName: "fooEventRule"
    })
}))
```

Hope this helps.